# Нужны ли запятые в приведенных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Он должен был не просто победить, а нокаутировать заносчивого соперника(,) и получить награду за самый зрелищный бой вечера.

Этот юноша должен был стать не просто правителем, а чуть ли не любимцем народа(,) и вершить судьбу целого государства.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з

Comment: Мы не выполняем д/з, но можем помочь и поправить, если вы дополните вопрос своими рассуждениями.

Comment: Вопрос нестандартный  и на д/з не похож. В этих предложениях разные синтаксические конструкции, хотя внешне они сходны. Но даже при одинаковом решении объяснение будет разное.